# При выборе select option добавить один скрипт в head и другой удалить

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

Есть в `head` такой скрипт

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" id="Russian_Azerbaijan" src="../translates/lang_Azerbaijan.js"></script>
</head>
```

Есть такие выпадающие кнопки

```
<select id="user_language" onchange="set_lang();"><option id="Azerbaijan_az" value="Azerbaijan_en" disabled="disabled">Azerbaijan</option><option id="Azerbaijan_en" value="Azerbaijan_en">American</option><option id="Azerbaijan_ru" value="Azerbaijan_ru">Russian</option></select>
```

Теперь так сделать чтоб при выборе **American**
в `head` удалялся

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="Russian_Azerbaijan" src="../translates/lang_Azerbaijan.js"></script>
```

и вставился

и обратно тоже самое

Answer (score 1):

уже разобрался вот  если кому нужен..

```
function set_lang(e){
   if(!e&&!document.getElementById('languages'))return;
   var o=document.getElementById('languages');
   o.parentNode.removeChild(o);
   o = document.createElement('script');
   o.type = 'text/javascript';
   o.id = 'languages';
   o.async = !1;
   o.src = "/js/translates/lang_"+e+".js";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(o);
};
```